# How do I configure multiple SSIDs (wireless networks) on a Sonicwall Sonicpoint?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssid

I have a SonicWALL NSA240, SonicPoint N and NetGear GS748T and would like to set up two SSIDs.

I would like a "BusinessPrivate SSID" with access to the business network and the internet, and a "BusinessGuest SSID" which only has access to the internet.

Supposedly, this should be cake with VLANs - but I apparently do not understand the finer concepts of VLANs, and cannot get [the configuration I found here to work](https://www.fuzeqna.com/sonicwallkb/consumer/kbdetail.asp?kbid=5133).

When I plug the SonicPoint into the switch, I cannot get it to appear under "SonicPoints" in the SonicWALL.  If I plug it into Port X4 on the Sonicwall, it appears, but I cannot assign more than one zone to the port (without using VLANs, which I don't understand).

Can someone explain, in simple terms, how to configure this hardware to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, the secret was to plug the SonicPoint directly into the Sonicwall on port X4, but then to create additional VLAN interfaces under X4.

```
Name    Zone IP Address   Subnet Mask    IP Assignment  Status
X4      WLAN 192.168.2.1  255.255.255.0  Static         100 Mbps full-duplex 
X4:V100 WLAN 192.168.3.1  255.255.255.0  Static         VLAN Sub-Interface  
X4:V200 WLAN 192.168.4.1  255.255.255.0  Static         VLAN Sub-Interface
```

"WLAN" is the "Zone".  You can assign different zones if necessary.

Under "SonicPoint / Virtual Access Point > Virtual Access Points":

```
# SSID              VLAN ID Authentication  Cipher Max Clients
1 Private Wireless  100  Both            WEP    16            
2 Guest Wireless    200  Open            None   16
```

Note, if you're using WEP, the key(s) are set under "SonicPoint / SonicPoints" under the appropriate provisioning profile.

Add the Virtual Access Points to a Virtual Access Points Group, then assign that group under "Virtual Access Point Settings" in the provision profile.

Under "Firewall / Access Rules", give the private wireless access to the LAN and deny the guest wireless access to the LAN:

```
#  Priority  Source          Destination  Service  Action  Users
1  1         X4 Subnet       Any          Any      Allow   All            
2  2       X4:V100 Subnet  Any          Any      Allow   All              
3  3         X4:V200 Subnet  Any          Any      Deny    All
```

That's about all there is to it.  Plenty of other configuration options to play with though, depending on your requirements.